# ReactJS onClick event on an array element

Tags: arrays, reactjs, onclick

I need to select images in an image grid. Currently, I can only select one image at a time. When selecting one, the other unselects. I'd like to select every image I want (many images selected at a time). I can't activate a isToggle boolean on each element with onClick event.

```
class Gallery extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    //isToggleOn: true,
    selected: '',
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick = key => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      //isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn,
      selected: key,
    }));
    //console.log(this.state)
  } 

  render(){
  //const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Container>
    <Row >
    <Col>
    <div style={styles.root}>
      <GridList cellHeight={160} style={styles.gridList} cols={3}>
        {tileData.map((tile,i) => (
          <GridListTile key={i} cols={tile.cols || 1} onClick={() => this.handleClick(tile)} >
            <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} style={this.state.selected === tile  ? styles.inputClicked:styles.inputNormal} />
          </GridListTile>
        ))}
      </GridList>
    </div>
    </Col>
    </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}
}


export default Gallery;

I can only select one image at a time. I expect to select many at a time.
```

Comment: Reformat your code to make it has a better look. I even don't know the presentation of `tileData` array. maybe it contains the problem you asked

Comment: tileData is an array with the properties of the tile (imgsource and title), so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the tile gets clicked, you need to add to an array of selected tiles like this:

```
handleClick = tile => {
    this.setState({
      selected: this.state.selected.concat([tile]),
    });
  }
```

then when rendering, you can check if the tile is selected something like this:

```
<img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} style={isSelected(this.state.selected, tile)  ? styles.inputClicked:styles.inputNormal} />
```

with:

```
isSelected = (selected, tile) => {
    // some logic to check that the tile is already selected e.g.
    return selected.find(tileItem => tileItem.title === tile.title)
}
```

Ensure to initialise your selected state to [] in constructor :

```
this.state = {
    selected: [],
    };
```

UPDATE:

If you want to remove tiles too, you'd have to do something like this:

```
handleClick = tile => {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    if(selected.find(item ==> item.title === tile.title)) {
       // need to remove tile
       this.setState({
         selected: selected.filter(item => item.tile !== tile.title),
       });
    } else {
       this.setState({
         selected: this.state.selected.concat([tile]),
       });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, now I can select several individual images, but how can I unselect them as well with onClick event?

Comment: No worries. You’d use array filter to remove the tile.

Comment: But should I add another function that filters the selected tiles? Or how would you do it?